# style being attatched to <html> tag from outside of style sheets

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm developing an online store using wp e-commerce plugin.

Whilst working on it locally the problem didn't occur, but after I started testing it online a large gap began appearing before the top of the page. Using Firebug I've been able to see that the styling causing it is:
html {margin-top: 28px !important; }

which firebug is telling me comes from a file that has the same name as the page ie: if example.com/products-page is the page being viewed it says that the style in question is being created by http://example.com/products-page on (line63)

I have used dreamweaver to search the entire wordpress folder locally for the style causing the error but it doesn't exist - it seems to be only occurring when the site is live online. I considered that possibly something could be getting added at a server level so I uploaded the site to an account on a different host - but same problem.

I'm using a reset.css file that would normally overcome this style being recognised - but than !important is what keeps it from being ignored.

Any insights or suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost surely your problem [**Wordpress Admin Bar**](http://www.websynn.com/2011/04/11/wordpress-html-margin-top-28px-important/) ..

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll discuss implementing the css and coding suggestions suggested in that article.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're logged in to the WordPress admin panel? The new WordPress admin-bar adds some css to the header:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much - problem solved. I'm just guessing I didn't see it during development on localhost as it's running a slightly older version of wordpress that doesn't include that navigation bar. Thanks guys for your help - greatly appreciated